# Should DTO models be used as parameters when calling methods of an interface contract?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, architecture

My team and I are having a discussion about whether or not to use DTO models as method parameters of an interface contract. Bear in mind that we are using an interface so we can use dependency inversion and mock this as a dependency for unit testing.

```
public interface IContract {
    object Method1(DTOModel model);
}

public class Implementation1 {
    public object Method1(DTOModel model) {
        //do stuff with Property1 and Property2
    }
}

public class Implementation2 {
    public object Method1(DTOModel model) {
       //do stuff with Property3 and Property4
    }
}

public class DTOModel {
    public string Property1 {get;set;}
    public string Property2 {get;set;}
    public string Property3 {get;set;}
    public string Property4 {get;set;}
}
```

The scenario is this: We are trying to be flexible in our implementations so that we could possibly use both of them at the same time. I disagree with this approach unless both implementations require the same information in the contract. In my opinion, that would be a separate contract/implementation or the current contract must change and only 1 implementation should be used at the same time.

My thoughts are that if you use a DTO in this fashion you are defeating the contract by allowing two different implementations to behave differently based on which properties are set. It also means that the consumer has to know which implementation is being used to know which properties are required for the operation to be completed. Finally, it means that both implementations have access to properties of each other where they are not necessary.

The way I would fix this is to instead pass properties of `DTOModel` to the implementation and make `Implementation2` adhere to that contract:

```
public object Method1(string property1, string property2) {
    //do stuff with property1 and property2
}
```

The question is: Is it acceptable to pass in a DTO like above knowing that your implementations don't rely on the whole contract and/or rely on different parts of the contract in order to do different things? Or should the contract be explicit in what the implementation needs to do its work?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: 
To clarify, both of these implementations have the same purpose but operate on different providers. For example, we may be using 2 membership providers and one provider requires 2 specific properties, and the other requires 2 different properties. Their purpose is the same in that they will both be authenticating a user, however the means by which each implementation does so is different.

Comment: If the method doesn't *need* the whole DTO object then it shouldn't require the whole DTO object. You always want to avoid tight coupling when you can. Requiring an unrelated DTO object for the method just because it happens to have the information the method needs seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I agree with your analysis. I would pass the properties of the DTO. I'm not sure if passing the DTO is a violation of a specific principal or pattern - it might be, it has a bit of code smell to it, but my issue is that it's ambiguous and the intent is not clear to someone implementing the contract in the future.

Let's say someone comes along and implements Implementation3 and they get this DTO. They have all of these properties and they're not sure what is useful and what isn't. Further, as requirements grow and change, that DTO is sure to grow and change. Before you know it, the DTO doesn't have 4 properties. Maybe it has 8 or 10 properties because each person building an implementation may have slightly different requirements for parameters. You may end up at a point where someone implements the contract and gets an object passed as a parameter with 8 useless properties.

I would either pass in the specific properties that are explicitly useful to the method given any implementation or create multiple DTOs and pass in whichever is relevant. In that case, a contract for the DTO itself may be an option. If the requirements for each method are that different, create separate methods.

Comment: I agree completely. The purpose of using a DTO seem sound for wanting to be flexible, but the implications frightened me. We needed some outside input.

Comment: I've updated the question to be a little more specific in case it changes your answer.

Comment: I need more context / code to discuss further but when you say 2 different providers for authenticating users requiring 2 properties - are we talking like an EmailAuthProvider, TokenAuthProvider, UsernameAuthProvider taking perhaps an e-mail, username, token, pw, etc? Maybe use 1 provider - with explicit methods. So AuthenticationProvider with AuthByUsername(uname, pw), AuthByEmail(email, pw), AuthByToken(token)? You could still use the contract if other implementations are necessary. Throw an exception if a specific provider does not support a specific type of auth so the developer knows.

Answer (score 2):

If a method only needs a couple of arguments, pass them directly as parameters.  If it needs more than three or four arguments, refactoring it to use a DTO is probably not a bad idea.

However, if you go this route, create DTO classes specific to those operations (don't share one massive, messy class all over the place).  If your implementations are so fundamentally different that they cannot share the same input parameters, I would go back to the drawing board and review whether or not they should share the same interface.  Also, importantly, don't pass around the same DTO's that you use in any other layer (transport, UI, etc.) - that leads to nasty coupling that shouldn't exist.

Comment: To clarify, both implementations would be doing something similar, say logging someone in via a membership provider. The difference would be they are 2 membership providers, and each membership provider requires a different set of values to authenticate, say impl1 uses username and password, impl2 uses some kind of signed key or something. Probably a bad example but that's essentially what we're debating.

Comment: In that case, I might look at creating an "AuthenticationProvider" class (or something like that) which can be extended for different purposes - e.g. UserCredentialAuthenticationProvider and SignedKeyAuthenticationProvider.  Your interface method can then simply accept an AuthenticationProvider and each implementation can cast it to the appropriate type (hopefully with a nice meaningful exception being thrown in the event that the wrong type is passed).

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I think this approach will break Liskov principle.

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming that states that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e. an object of type T may be substituted with any object of a subtype S) without altering any of the desirable properties of T (correctness, task performed, etc.).

In your example if you change `Implementation1` with `Implementation2` this principle won't be satisfied anymore.

Comment: The two implementations would still be satisfied by the contract and could still be swapped easily, the only issue is the excess properties hanging onto the DTO. I felt it also broke the Single Responsibility rule since you have 1 object serving 2 purposes.

Comment: If program act the same when you change implementations then fine but I am suspicious because you change two different properties of the DTO object. Yes, agree for single responsibility. It is definitely code smell for me.

Comment: I've updated the question to be a little more specific in case it changes your answer.